# C programming on IAR

Tags: c, iar, stm32

I am coding on the IAR platform and want to do the following. I have a `typedef` as follows

```
struct timer {
  uint32_t start;
  uint32_t interval;
};

typedef (void) (*etimer_cb) (int,void*);

struct etimer {
  struct timer timer;
  struct etimer* next;
  etimer_cb p;
};
```

After these I declare the following variable:

```
struct etimer periodic;
```

but it comes up with an error:

```
"periodic" is declared with a never completed type.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `;` after the ending braces of the struct def maybe? I normally just put them there, not sure if they are needed.

Comment: oh thats a typing error on my part, those are there

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `()` from around `void`.
`uint32_t` is not a predefined type. You need to `#include <stdint.h>`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
struct timer{
  uint32_t start;
  uint32_t interval;
};
typedef void (*etimer_cb)(int, void *);
struct etimer{
  struct timer timer;
  struct etimer* next;
  etimer_cb p;
};
```

But I prefer to **NOT** hide the pointerness of the function

```
#include <stdint.h>
struct timer{
  uint32_t start;
  uint32_t interval;
};
typedef void etimer_cb(int, void *);
struct etimer{
  struct timer timer;
  struct etimer* next;
  etimer_cb *p;
};
```

Comment: I don't think it's meant as hiding as much as simply a convention to typedef a function pointer. After all, you don't call a function using '*' to dereference it's name. I've seen way more uses of the op's declaration compared to yours. My guesstimate is 80-20 in favor of the first one.

Comment: As I said, it's a preference (first snippet used OP's style). I just like to have the stars visible and maybe influence OP to use my style :P